# jQuery throws an error that iframe.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-api

Any function to target that same `iframe` object is not working and the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: target[0].getElementsById is not a function
```

I want to access the value of objects of an iframe

```js
function fetchmap(target) {
  console.log(target[0])
  var el = target[0].getElementsByTagName('input #pac-input');
  var e = target[0].getElementsById('pac-input')
  console.log(el);

};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 px-4 md-form form-group" id="placefinder">
 <iframe id="iframe" src="//developers.google.com/my-business/content/tools/placeid-lookup" width="100%" height="400px" onload="fetchmap($(this))"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `getElementById` (singular), not `getElementsById` (plural). It returns a single element.

Also note that the elements in a document inside the iframe are *not* descendants of the iframe itself. You have to use `iframe.contentDocument.getElementById()`.

Comment: thanks, but I have this problem : Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame. and ifram src is https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/tools/placeid-lookup

Comment: Well, that's a different matter. Scripts aren't allowed to access the DOM structure of windows and iframes that are loaded from different domains (to prevent malicious code from hijacking your browser).